# programatically mimic events on a Mac

Tags: macos, terminal, safari, applescript, safari-extension

How can I listen for an event on my Mac, record the event and than execute it programatically.

For example, I want to reload extension I made programatically. For that I need to go to Extension Builder and click Reload each time I make a change. When I press Reload, some code on OS X gets executed that notifies the Safari that it need to reload it's extensions. I would like to do the same thing, but programatically. Possibly by recording this event, and later launching it programatically.

This is the Reload button whose functionality I want to mimic.

[image]

Comment: if you want to simulate click and user events, you must use "System Events" with command keystroke (keyboard simulation) or click command. it requires to know which UI element (button of which group, which window,...you want to click on)

Comment: Thanks for stopping by. I don't like this way, because I need to wait for GUI of an app to actually open, if I want to perform keystroke.